# Azure Iot Edge avoid sending MQTT messages upstream

Tags: azure, mqtt, iot

When creating a layered deployment in the iot edge portal, it seems you cannot remove common_route which sends all messages upstream. We use this layered deployment when deploying our runtime. How can I stop mqtt messages from being send upstream ? and only be send locally on my IoT edge device ?

If it cannot be removed, does it affect the pricing if the messages are send upstream, but nothing is happening to it, I presume the queue just fills up ?

I've tried numerous routing tests, I have a local test, where I can remove the common route from my deployment manifest.

Comment: Does anyone not know this ?